Does Magento integrate with Quickbooks online
We are currently using Quickbooks, Wholesale and Manufacturing, a desktop version, and we need to upgrade and are looking at Quickbooks online version.  Does Magento 2 integrate with Quickbooks online, and/or do we need a plug in/extension to make it integrate?  OR, do you have a better suggestion than Quickbooks?
We don't believe we can just create invoices in Magento 2 because we need to edit the shipping costs, as we pass on a savings to some of our customers and we need to add handling/drop ship fees and add on items that customers add to the order AFTER submitting it.
We do need some sort of invoicing program, because we create purchase orders for items that we buy in from our vendors.

Yes.
A simple google search produces links to several plugins:

Amasty - https://amasty.com/magento-2-quickbooks-integration-service.html
Meetanshi - https://commercemarketplace.adobe.com/meetanshi-magento-2-quickbooks-online-integration.html
Webkul - https://store.webkul.com/magento2-quickbooks-qbo-connector.html


We understand that you are planning to use Magento to sell your products directly to the consumer (B2C) using the Community edition or use the (B2B) option that comes with Magento Enterprise (paid).
At first glance an initial integration can be done using something like Zappier integration or using the existing modules like meetanshi which you can get from the Magento marketplace.
Regarding the invoicing, there should be not an issue to edit the order after it's placed on the free version. Event advanced editing modules can be found to personalize the editing process further.
If your main customers is Bussiness, you might be more interesed on the B2B version as it allows to create quotes and manage them with the customers directly.
